# How to do a recursive download with gwget (wget frontend)?

Tags: networking, debian, wget

I usually run `wget` with the `-np -r` options, but it doesn't include a preview of the queue size, so I'm checking out the `wget` frontend `gwget` (on debian). I can't get the recursive option to work; does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**
Unfortunately, my initial test was a bit hasty.  It seems that Gwget has a bug:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=628514

https://bugs.launchpad.net/gwget/+bug/626607

---

The following directions *should* work but doesn't seem to:

1. Open Gwget
2. Press the "New" icon or select Archive -> New from the menu.
3. In the URL box put the URL of the site that you want to recursively download.
4. Press OK.
5. A Dialog Box should appear with various options for recursive download.
6. Choose one that makes sense for you.

[image: Wget Recursive Options Dialog]

Comment: this is exactly what I've been doing and it stops after downloading the first page.
On the recursive options box all radio boxes are selected and I cannot change anything.
Really annoyed with it.

Comment: there's a bug.I'm not alone then.Thanks for finding that